# Unable to get all the elements in ImmutableMltiDict in Flask

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, tuples

I have an ImmutableMultiDict([('1', 'a'), ('2', 'a'), ('3', 'a'), ('4', 'a'), ('5', 'a'), ('6', 'a'), ('7', 'a'), ('8', 'a'), ('9', 'a'), ('10', 'a')]).

When I run the following code:-

```py
f = request.form
app.logger.debug(f) # This gives out ImmutableMultiDict([('1', 'a'), ('2', 'a'), ('3', 'a'), ('4', 'a'), ('5', 'a'), ('6', 'a'), ('7', 'a'), ('8', 'a'), ('9', 'a'), ('10', 'a')])
for i in f:
    app.logger.debug(i) # This gives out 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in each iteration of the loop.
 return 'hi'
```

I expected the output :
('1','a') in the first iteration, then ('2', 'a') in the next etc.

Do you have any idea what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dict-like things in Python give you the keys when you iterate over them.  To get what you're looking for, use `.items()`:

```
for i in f.items():
    app.logger.debug(i)
```

Comment: Nope. There's an Attribute error.
AttributeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: If it's python-2.x, use `.iteritems()` instead.

Comment: Did you use `.items()` or `.item()`?

Comment: Ok, yeah. I used item(). It works now! Thanks a billion!